# PC frozen at startup, not booting

Tags: boot, troubleshooting, hardware-failure

I am trying to fix my Gateway desktop. About 6 months ago it stopped working and since then I started using a laptop. But now I want to fix it since it's much more powerful than my laptop.

The problem is that when I turn it on, the fans start, the hard drive starts spinng but the  screen is always blank. Not even a BIOS screen shows up. A clue as to what's wrong may be the fact that when I connect my wireless keyboard the light on it's USB receiver is constantly lit. On a working computer that receiver only lights up when I press a key. But when I connect it to this desktop it's lit non-stop.

Another clue is, when I press and hold the power button it doesn't turn off. But if I unplug the desktop and plug it back in, and it starts again, if I press and hold the power button it shuts off. But it I start it again same problem.

I don't remember what exactly happened the day it stopped working but I don't remember anything crazy happening like a short circuit or anything.

Does anyone have a clue as to what may be wrong?

### P.S.

Hard drive isn't corrupt, I was able to open it using a external hard drive connector on my laptop and see it's contents.

Comment: Looks like a motherboard failure to me

Answer (score 0):

it looks like normal problem with unused Desktops for long time. So i think Cleanning the dust from RAM slot & Reconnecting the RAM may help you to get bios Screen. if it works let me know.